# SPFx Version support for On Premise Server (2019)

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx

We're currently standing up a sharepoint-server environment, migrating from SP 2010. There are a handful of webparts and event handlers that will need to be rewritten to support 2019.

I've gone down the path of looking at SPFx and all of the related tooling.

I'm more than comfortable with the change, but what I can't determine is when/if SPFx features were designed for sharepoint-online only or aren't supported with the current version of 2019 and will be supported in a future release.

- Is there a way to determine what version of SPFx is supported?
- Do CU's or other patches update this support frequently?

If there is going to be a drastic difference in parity between online and on-prem, I'd like to be able to know before continuing to develop.

- What is supported in each SPFx version?

I can mostly look at changelogs for the answer to this one, but are there any gotchas I should know about? (might be crossing an *opinion* border here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPFx version 1.4.1 is supported with 2019. This will likely not be updated to any newer version of SPFx.

Feature-wise, I don't believe this is documented in a single location. You would need to review each feature release, and even then there are going to be cloud-only features that aren't going to be available in SharePoint 2019.

Answer (score 3):

Supported SharePoint Framework version for the SharePoint 2019 is SharePoint Framework v1.4.1.

Read this article for details around supported development capabilities in the SharePoint 2019:[SharePoint Server 2019 development platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-2019-development-platform)

Besides, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki) for each version of SPFx.